# Fourier decomposition small fluctuations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, cosmology

I am studying Cosmology book by Weinberg. I am struggling over section 5.2 where he wants to decompose the perturbations, the scalar and tensor one because we don't care of the vector pertubations being supressed by expansion, in the Fourier space. Now I know that we can imagine the (metetric and matter) perturbations as travelling on a background space, in this case is flat, and so we can make the decomposition. But I don't understand the firts part of page 229 where he justify the decomposition by writing:

*Let us first see how this works out for the scalar modes. Because the unperturbed metric, energy density, etc. are independent of position, the general solution for the corresponding perturbed quantities may be written as a superposition of plane wave solutions, whose spatial variation is given by factors $exp(i\vec q · \vec x)$, where $\vec q$ is a real wave vector, over which we must integrate.*

-I explain this in this way(if you can correct me please):I have einstein equations and conservation equations(pag. 226). If I take unpertubed quantities independent of comoving coordinate then in these equations I can solve by going in Fourier space. But, why can I go to Fourier space? Because in those equations I have ordinary differential operators(in comoving coordinates)? I don't understand...

Then he continues

*The coefficient of $exp(i\vec q · \vec x)$ in each of the scalar perturbations $A(\vec x, t)$, $B(\vec x, t)$, etc. is a solution of coupled ordinary differential equations with time as the independent variable, obtained by replacing $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$ with $iq_j$ everywhere in the equations presented in Section 5.1. The differential equations obtained in this way depend on $q=|\vec q|$, but not on the direction of $\vec q$, so the solutions can be written as superpositions of independent q-dependent normal modes, each characterized by a set of perturbations $A_{nq}(t)$, $B_{nq}(t)$, etc., with an overall normalization factor $α_n(\vec q)$ carrying a discrete index n that labels the various independent solutions. These normalization factors depend on the initial conditions, which of course are not rotationally invariant if they were then there would be no galaxies or stars — so the $α_n(\vec q)$  depend on the direction of $\vec q$, but the solutions $A_{nq}(t), B_{nq}(t)$ can be chosen to depend only on $q=|\vec q|$. Thas is we write
$A(\vec x,t)=\sum_n \int d^3q \alpha_{n}(\vec q) A_{nq}(t)e^{i\vec q \vec x}$
$B(\vec x,t)=\sum_n \int d^3q \alpha_{n}(\vec q) B_{nq}(t)e^{i\vec q \vec x}$*
etc..

Why I have a normalization factor? And why all modes have the SAME normalization factor?

In the end, if I wrote this equation I would write simply
$A(\vec x,t)=\int d^3q A_{q}(t)e^{i\vec q \vec x} $